# What is wrong with this Heap sort implementation in C?

Tags: c, sorting, heap

I have been trying to find error in this implementation of Heap sort algorithm in C but am unable to find it. It is compiling fine but when I execute the program it gives an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int cmp(int *a, int *b){return *a-*b;}
void swap(int *a, int *b){
int temp;
temp=*a; *a=*b; *b=temp;}
void sift_down(int *A,int parent, int n){
        int child;
        if((child=2*parent+1)<n){
                if(child+1<n && cmp(A+child,A+child+1)<0){
                        child++;
                }}
        if(cmp(A+parent,A+child)<0){
                swap(A+parent,A+child);
                sift_down(A,child,n);
        }}
void build_heap(int A[], int n){
        int i;
        for(i=(n/2)-1;i>=0;i--){
                sift_down(A,i,n);
        }
}
void heapsort(int A[], int n){
        int active;
        build_heap(A,n);
        for(active=n-1;active>0;active--){
                swap(A,A+active);
                sift_down(A,0,active);
        }
}
int main(){
        int A[]={13,16,14,10,15,17,18,30,25},i,n;
        n=sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
        heapsort(A,n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                printf("%d\t",A[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? A runtime error or "just" a wrong result?

Comment: @PMF it just gave a runtime error. I

Comment: @JBRWilkinson No, this isn't homework. Just me trying to implement various sorting algorithms..

Comment: okay, so what is the runtime error? segfault?

Comment: I run it. Giving `segmesntation fault(core dumped)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting bracing style. Untangled, your function `sift_down` looks like this:

```
void sift_down(int *A, int parent, int n)
{
    int child;

    if ((child = 2 * parent + 1) < n) {
        if (child + 1 < n && cmp(A + child, A + child + 1) < 0) {
            child++;
        }
    }

    if (cmp(A + parent, A + child) < 0) {
        swap(A + parent, A + child);
        sift_down(A, child, n);
    }
}
```

The `if`s shouldn't be consecuteve, they should be nested. Otherwise you'll access a `child` beyond the end of the array in the `cmp` and `swap` functions - segmentaion fault.

So your function should look like this:

```
void sift_down(int *A, int parent, int n)
{
    int child = 2 * parent + 1;

    if (child < n) {
        if (child + 1 < n && cmp(A + child, A + child + 1) < 0) {
            child++;
        }

        if (cmp(A + parent, A + child) < 0) {
            swap(A + parent, A + child);
            sift_down(A, child, n);
        }
    }
}
```

(I've also taken the liberty to move the assignment to `child` out of the `if` condition.)

Comment: what OP program does? I run it. The result is array elements are sorted randomly.

Comment: @SGG There was a misuse of braces on my part. M Oehm's sift_down  function resolves this.

Comment: @user2390548. what is the aim of your program?

Comment: @SGG: It sorts the list of integers.

Comment: @SGG the program aims to sort the elements of the given array in ascending order using Heap sort function.